# Python program for converting decimal to binary

Tags: python

Below is a Python program, that I have written, that converts decimal numbers to binary. However, I'm getting errors. Can anyone help?

```
def decimaltobin(n):

    (ls,count,i)=([],0,0)
    while(n>0):
        ls[i]=n%2
        n=n/2
        i=i+1
    while(i>0):
        print(ls[i])
        i=i-1

decimaltobin(8)
```

Comment: this is code for binary to decimal conversion

Comment: Post the error you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `ls` as an empty list, which means you cannot set element `ls[i]` as a value since `ls[i]` does not exist. For your code, you should add the new value to the list with, for example, `ls.append(n%2)`. You also need to decrement the `i` to `i-1` after your iterations in the first while loop to correctly call `ls[i]` in the second while loop.

```
def decimaltobin(n):
    (ls,count,i)=([],0,0)
    while(n>0):
        ls.append(n%2)
        n=n//2
        i=i+1
    i=i-1
    while(i>=0):
        print(ls[i])
        i=i-1
```

Comment: Surely you mean `n=n//2` in line 5, or it will break :)

Comment: I assumed n was an integer which would return the same as using //

Comment: Well, it broke for me on Python 3.6.5 under windows 10. Think it may react differently in different environments...